# Estimating position with a Kalman Filter

Tags: matlab, math, sensors, kalman-filter

I am doing a project on Indoor Positioning. I have used NS2 and a matlab GUI named Senelex to find the original and estimated positions of nodes. Now I want to use a Kalman filter to estimate the position of the node/target.

For example:

If I consider the velocity of the target as constant, how can I use the determined values of estimated or original position of nodes to provide as input to a Kalman filter.

The following are the estimated position and original position of nodes.

```
ori = [6.62650602409639 194.444444444445;
        6.62650602409639 10.6837606837607;
        192.168674698795 7.83475783475797;
        192.168674698795 191.595441595442;
        70.4819277108434 171.652421652422;
        129.518072289157 168.803418803419;
        24.6987951807229 144.586894586895;
        42.7710843373494 79.0598290598291];


est   = [6.62650602409639 194.444444444445;
            6.62650602409639 10.6837606837607;
            192.168674698795 7.83475783475797;
            192.168674698795 191.595441595442;
            70.7600705547484 171.847603055024;
            129.443055817301 168.734648868329;
            25.01956026761   144.890243978875;
            42.6058125534278 79.1446327727804];
```

How can I use these as inputs to a Kalman filter and estimate the target using a Kalman filter?

Comment: This question could be much improved by stating what you have tried. The correct answer right now would be copying the chapter about Kalman filtering from any book, which is hopefully not what you need.

Comment: If you need help with the code, you should post some here on [SO] so we can help you. If you have conceptual questions, check out our sister site [dsp.se].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest by starting with the relatively straight forward tutorial on Kalman filters: An [Introduction to the Kalman Filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/media/pdf/kalman_intro.pdf). [The Kalman Filter](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/kalman/) site has fair number of good resources, including links to a Matlab toolbox. The Kalman filter implementation is not a very complex program, once you have the equations.

Here are some links to some Java versions of Kalman filters:

- http://web.ist.utl.pt/davidmiguel/KalmanExample.zip
- http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2009/12/java-implementation-of-kalman-filter.html
- http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.com/2009/12/simulation-and-kalman-filter-for-3rd.html

I'm sure there is source code available for most programming languages. These examples are ones with which I've worked.

Comment: And i read Kalman filter will predict the future positions. How its going to predict the future position when there is much difference between current and next position in the output i have got. (check ori data in my question).

Pls correct if am wrong sir.

Comment: @Desizner: The fundamental idea behind a Kalman filter is that it uses the most reliable information it has to predict the next state. It measures reliability by the variance of the information sources. So big or small change in position, the filter will do the best it can to predict the next state. If certain conditions are met, a Kalman filter is optimal. If the target velocity is constant as you indicate, that can be modeled and used by the Kalman filter.